# Opening socket connection in Firefox Add-On

Tags: sockets, firefox-addon

I want to open a socket connection (outgoing, not listen on an nsIServerSocket) from within a Firefox add-on in JavaScript.  The connection should be TCP to localhost on a specified port, and will be used to communicate with another process running on the machine.

How can I open such a client socket?  I found the API documentation for interfaces like nsISocketTransport on developer.mozilla.org, but that still doesn't help me put the pieces together.  It doesn't even mention that the socket can be for TCP there, either, so I'm not even 100% sure this is the interface I need.  All I could find so far is more about nsIServerSocket.  Note:  I'm not using the add-on SDK, and work on a bootstrapped add-on directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're on the right track. I use nsISocketTransport and nsISocketTransportService in KeeFox to enable cross-process communication but it is the related listener and callback interfaces that complete the picture.

This file should contain some useful example code: https://github.com/luckyrat/KeeFox/blob/master/Firefox%20addon/KeeFox/modules/session.js

It opens a secure TCP connection on a specific port, making regular attempts to connect to the server port and handling the security exceptions that arise from the use of a self-signed certificate.

I use the following interfaces although you might need slightly different ones depending on exact situation:

```
QueryInterface: XPCOMUtils.generateQI([Ci.nsIBadCertListener2,
                                       Ci.nsIInterfaceRequestor,
                                       Ci.nsIStreamListener,
                                       Ci.nsITransportEventSink,
                                       Ci.nsIOutputStreamCallback])
```

Some of the callbacks defined on those interfaces are contained within this 2nd file which extends the basic session object prototype to apply the specific communication protocol that KeeFox uses (JSON-RPC):

https://github.com/luckyrat/KeeFox/blob/master/Firefox%20addon/KeeFox/modules/json.js

https://github.com/luckyrat/KeeFox/blob/master/Firefox%20addon/KeeFox/modules/KF.js creates some timers and starts the connection process with the code below but you probably won't need to look into that file in much detail.

```
this.KeePassRPC = new jsonrpcClient(); // defined in json.js and session.js

// make the initial connection to KeePassRPC
// (fails silently if KeePassRPC is not reachable)
this.KeePassRPC.connect();

// start regular attempts to reconnect to KeePassRPC
this.KeePassRPC.reconnectSoon();
```

Out of interest, do you have to use a raw TCP connection? That was the only option 4 years ago when I created KeeFox but I'm currently working on a Web Socket solution instead so it might be worth thinking about that option too if you haven't already. It's certainly a lot simpler than getting your head around the raw socket interfaces.

Comment: Thanks for the elaborate answer!  You're right, I don't need a raw socket.  I thought I do, but I found out in the mean time that my server wants requests instead as HTTP with POST payload data, so I'm using a nsIHttpChannel now instead.

Comment: However, a different server component I may want to use in the future too indeed requires a raw socket connection, so I may need to use that stuff anyway.  Is there a way to use a generic nsIChannel (or so) for non-HTTP connections?

Comment: Yeah it's very similar but you just won't need to worry about the certificates. Line 101 in session.js is a commented out version that can be used with non secure connections: var transport = transportService.createTransport(null, 0, this.address, this.port, null);

Comment: Thanks for this man. I'm trying to talk to other applications. Like tell IE to open a newtab. Or Excel to open a new worksheet. Do you have any ideas on how to do these?

Answer (score 1):

While the answer given above is very good for my original question, I think it may be of interest to also post what I now do instead - I figured out that the server doesn't neet a raw connection but instead wants HTTP requests.  For this, a very good source for information is https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Creating_Sandboxed_HTTP_Connections as well as the API page for `nsIHttpChannel` plus some more interfaces linked from there (`nsIUploadChannel`, input streams and so on).

In particular, this is the code I now use to make the HTTP request and receive its answer:

```
var ch = NetUtil.newChannel (HTTP_URL);
ch.QueryInterface (Components.interfaces.nsIHttpChannel);
// Here you can set HTTP request headers, like authorization.

var s = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/io/string-input-stream;1"]
        .createInstance (Components.interfaces.nsIStringInputStream);
s.setData (DATA_FOR_SERVER, DATA_FOR_SERVER.length);
ch.QueryInterface (Components.interfaces.nsIUploadChannel);

// I have JSON data, otherwise change the MIME type.
ch.setUploadStream (s, "application/json", -1);
ch.requestMethod = "POST";

s = ch.open ();
var avail = s.available ();
if (avail === 0)
  {
    s.close ();
    throw "Connecting failed.";
  }

var string = NetUtil.readInputStreamToString (s, avail, null);
s.close ();

dump ("Response code: " + ch.responseStatus);
dump ("Response data: " + string);
```