# Javascript access desktop application

Tags: javascript, sockets, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon, ipc

I'd like you to give a tip for my issue. I'm pretty new to javascript so I don't have such overview.

I have a desktop application - it's basically a storega for data (+ some GUI). And there's a set of Javascript files, which are ment to get data from desktop application.

These javascript files runs in every browser - for each browser I've made a extension wrapper. There is also a testing java-webkit browser, which injects these files directly (so no extension's API).

So I need to create communication API between Javascript and desktop application, which is able to run in every environment (browser-specific implementation would be too "expensive" to maintain).

So I was thinking of sockets. But there is only Websocket protocol support in javascript. Client looks simple, but I'm afraid that server-side would require too much work and dependecies.

Could you give me a tip, for other technologies, which compatible with my requirments?

And second question - to the sockets - would it be even possible to access socket on "localhost:port" from these's javascript files, when they are Content scripts running in page's context?

Thank you for advice.

Comment: see chrome messaging. dup of other similar questions on s.o.

Comment: One option in firefox is: You can open the file with command line options. Will this help? What about WebRTC?

Answer (score 2):

Sockets is the way to do it. @Luckyrat has provided some code on how to do it from a Firefox Addon:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/17459064/3791822